# rxfire subscription not firing in componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, rxjs, rxfire

I  am using rxfire to combine data from firestore in componentdidmount:

```
store$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(items$),  
      map(([store, items]) => ({ items, ...store })),    
    ).pipe(   
      withLatestFrom(categories$),       
      map(([store, categories]) => ({ categories, ...store })),
    ).subscribe(store => {      
      this.setState({ store: store, isLoading: false });
    })
```

The problem with this code is not firing and the screen stuck with the loading component. If I load the screen a second time it works. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not working until you reload, there could be a timing issue based on when `items$` and `categories$` emit their own values.

A safer approach to combining these observables would be with the `combineLatest()` feature from RxJS. It accepts an array of observables, and doesn't emit until it receives a value from **every** observable.

```
combineLatest([store$, items$, categories$]).pipe(
  map(([store, items, categories])=>({...store, ...items, ...categories})),
  tap(store=>this.setState({ store, isLoading: false })
).subscribe();
```

Keep in mind with `combineLatest()` that if any observable inside the array doesn't emit a value, then `combineLatest()` will never emit a value.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just changed this way:
```
 map(([store, products, categories])=>({products, categories, ...store})),
```
Else what do you mean if collection does'nt emit?: meaning if categories or products are empty we will not have value at all?

Comment: If categories or products are empty, then it will emit an empty array. I was talking about whether or not the observable emits zero values.

Comment: Also, if this did help you, please mark this answer as resolving your question.